# Pre-select a JavaFX CheckComboBox

Tags: checkbox, javafx, combobox, prompt, controlsfx

All the solutions I've read relate to [ComboBox](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ComboBox.html), not [CheckComboBox](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html). Using the ControlsFX `CheckComboBox` I've been able to add a few options into it using the controller code below. But I can't figure out how to pre-check an option at the time its added to the `ArrayList`, nor set Prompt Text.

```
... 
 @FXML
     public CheckComboBox<String> extras;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        extras.getItems().add("A");
        extras.getItems().add("B");
...
```

There doesn't seem to be a method like: `extras.getItems().add("A", true);` or `extras.getItems().get(0).setValue(true);`

The answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19181213/4731712) uses something like below, but this won't work for `CheckComboBox`:

`extras.setValue(value);` and
                `extras.setPromptText("Prompt Text");`

**Which leaves me asking:**

1. How do I set an option to checked/unchecked during initialization?
2. How do I set the prompt text on a `CheckComboBox`?

Comment: `extras.getCheckModel().check(0)`?

Comment: All I did was read the [documentation](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/control/CheckComboBox.html)...

Comment: @James_D, your link sadly doesn't get me to the documentation. But +1 for referencing the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent property for the "prompt test" is the "title":

```
checkComboBox.setTitle("myTitle");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help you..

```
checkComboBox.getCheckModel().check(0);
```